# How to host ASMX from Visual Studios on IIS?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asmx

I've created a web service in Visual Studios fully functional as I've been able to test it through localhost. I've attempted to publish it from visual studios following a few random guides but each time I try it I keep getting errors.

This is my most recent error.

```
Error   3   Web deployment task failed. (The specified credentials cannot be used with the authentication scheme 'Basic'.)

The specified credentials cannot be used with the authentication scheme 'Basic'.
Default credentials cannot be supplied for the Basic authentication scheme.
Parameter name: authType        0   0   RacoCS
```

My previous error was in reference to the URL I would try to publish it.

Answer (score 0):

Which publication method are you trying to use. Visual Studio let you publish your web apps in various ways. The less likely to have problems is to file system and then manually create a web site in IIS pointing to the directory where the publication files are. Good luck

Comment: I wasn't aware of that :S. I'm actually trying to use IIS to create the website. I tried to create a website in IIS by just using the directory where project is but no success.